# Create a linked service to the SAP OData endpoint - Connection failed

Tags: azure, odata, sap-gateway, sap-business-technology-platform, azure-synapse-analytics

I have been trying to create a linked service to the SAP OData endpoint for sales order header information in Microsoft Azure Synapse Analytics, but I am encountering an error - connection failed. I am getting the following error

> Failed to create odata connection to RequestUrl.
> An error occurred while sending the request.
> The remote name could not be resolved: 'vhcals4hci.dummy.nodomain'

How can I resolve it?

The URL `http://vhcals4hci.dummy.nodomain:50000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZBD_I_SALESDOCUMENT_E_CDS/` is working well in SAP VM